# Swift: property observers for computed properties

Tags: ios, swift, computed-properties

As far as I know, Swift allows us to set property observers for either stored and computed properties. But if computed property value depends on some backing store, property observers are not fired when these backing store values are changed:

```
public class BaseClass {
    private var privateVar1: Int = 0
    private var privateVar2: Int = 0
    public var property: Int {
        get {
            return privateVar1 * privateVar2
        }
        set {
            print("some setter without effect")
        }
    }
    private func changeSomeValues() {
        privateVar1 = 1
        privateVar2 = 2
    } 
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass {
    override var property: Int {
        didSet {
            print("didSet \(property)")
        }
    }
}
```

didSet of SubClass isn't called when changeSomeValues is called.

Let's consider a case: we have such BaseClass in a third-party framework. We define SubClass in our app. The question is: how can we rely on SubClass observers without knowledge about property nature: is it stored (and we can rely on observers) or computed (and then we can't expect firing observers each time when we expect it)? Is it possible? If no, is it an incapsulation violation?

Comment: Your code isn't valid and doesn't compile.  `property` is read-only.  If `property` is a read-write computed property then `didSet` will fire on the subclass, just as you would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behaviour is perfectly normal.   There is no way for the compiler to know which backing store really corresponds to which computed property.   Your backing store in this case is made up of private variables that will not be accessible outside the class itself.   So the only place where an "under the hood" change can occur is in the base class.  It is that class's prerogative to use its calculated properties (which will trigger the observers) or the backstore (which will not).

In your example, assuming you never want to allow "invisible" changes, the changeSomeValues() function is breaking its own rules and not respecting the contract it promised to its subclasses and callers.

Comment: For example, my base class is `UView` and a property is `frame`. Nobody knows if it's a computed or stored property because it's an implementation detail. The question is: can I rely on firing didSet for every  `frame` change each time I expect? If yes, how does it guaranteed and implemented? If no, does it make the whole concept of property observers useless?

Comment: Apple did not guaranty anything about observing the frame property. if you want to add that to the contract, you may be in a bind.   I haven't read the documentation in detail, but I believe frame is merely a convenience concept to access bounds & center which are the core concept that are really driving UIView's design.  In any case, Apple's documentation suggests using KVO for all view properties, which I dislike.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html

Comment: You also have to keep in mind that Swift hasn't been around that long. Objective-C has been king of the hill for year and the design of iOS/OSX frameworks has been strongly tainted by idiosyncrasies and limitations of older language constructs and progressive  evolution.   If iOS had been created using Swift, the APIs and class designs would leverage a lot more of Swift's features.  The good news is that Apple is progressively doing exactly that.  case in point being the move away from NSError return values to do/catch blocks.